# unable to see wallet balance using simplewallet restore

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, mnemonic-seed, blockchain

So I have been trying to restore my wallet using the seed and simplewallet, it asks for a wallet name, then a password and finally my seed, it says my wallet has been opened.

Then I set refresh and says 0 balance however I'm 1001% sure there's balance.

And I've received the message on bitmonerod.exe that I was syched

Currently synced 51127/1123555

Is this normal? Should I be seeing my balance already?

thanks...

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to see your balance when it is fully synced, i.e 1123555/1123555

Comment: anywhere i can download full blockchain recent file? official monero site seems to download blockchain.raw and I cant find a link on bitcointalk offical monero thread..

Comment: getmonero.org is the official site : [https://downloads.getmonero.org/blockchain.raw]

Answer (score 3):

Your issue brings up a very important distinction between Monero and Bitcoin Core. Namely, the daemon (aka the part that syncs the Monero blockchain) and the wallet (aka the part that tracks your balance) are separate things for Monero.

To use simplewallet, you need to connect it to a fully synced daemon. It is your the best interest from a privacy standpoint to use your own daemon, but simplewallet can connect to remote daemons without losing any security.

If your really need to see your balance before your daemon is synced, you could connect to a remote node ([How do I connect monero-wallet-cli to a remote node?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/1401/how-do-i-connect-simplewallet-to-a-remote-node)). Note than in doing so, you give up some privacy to the operator of that node.