# Is there any remote node list to connect simplewallet?

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, nodes

Someone previously asked how to connect simplewallet to a remote node here:

[How do I connect monero-wallet-cli to a remote node?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/1401/how-do-i-connect-simplewallet-to-a-remote-node)

However, is there any list of remote nodes available and their current status?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out https://moneroworld.com/#nodes for a current list and instructions.

Comment: Excellent! Tested on a wallet, where I had some funds stuck and was able to refresh blance & send some xmr really quick using node.moneroworld.com:18081

Comment: MoneroClub is down, and MoneroWorld changed the default port number.

Answer (score 2):

There are more open nodes listed here:

https://moneroworld.com/#nodes

Answer (score 2):

In addition to https://moneroworld.com/, there is also an automatically updated list of remote nodes on https://www.xmr.be/ (i.e. nodes on this list should always work).

DISCLAIMER: I am the author of this site, I advertise it here following a suggestion on this [Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/712odr/list_of_open_monero_nodes/dn8ac5h/). Please note that I am not the maintainer of the nodes listed on this site, I only wrote the script which look for them.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, you should explain what benefits it offers over the multiple answers already posted. Also, if (as implied by your user name) this site is yours, you need to be explicit about it. See [How not to be a spammer](/help/promotion).

Comment: Sorry, I've edited my answer. One benefit of my list (other than the larger number of listed nodes) is that it should always be up-to-date.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Maybe the rationale should be in the answer proper (comments are basically for follow-up questions etc).

Comment: the moneroworld nodes are also always up to date - both approaches use the same thing. One thing you provide is a secondary service. All of these approaches are centralized. So if moneroworld DNS goes down, people can try yours. Or if yours goes down, people can try moneroworld. Etc. Redundancy is the main benefit IMO. And that your harvesting 18081 nodes.

Comment: site is now down.