# Remotely connect to my full node with a Jaxx mobile wallet?

Tags: remote-access, mobile, third-party-wallets, jaxx

Will I be able to remotely connect to my own Monero full node from a Jaxx mobile wallet?

Will there be an easy method to choose between several nodes such as a Jaxx node, a node I run from home, the cloud or a [Moneroworld node](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/2498/is-there-any-remote-node-list-to-connect-simplewallet/2499#2499)?

Comment: Doubtful, most likely it will be run like a Mycelium wallet.

Answer (score 5):

I think initially you will not have a choice of node, but that's more of a question you should ask directly to jaxx. As the wallet is not out yet, we cannot look at it and tell you. Only Jaxx can tell you for sure at this point.

Being able to select your node would be a very important option on their wallet for us so I suggest we campaign for that.

Comment: Jaxx has noted that they intend to keep their own distributed, preferred node list to be utilized by their network.  They implied, but did not state explicitly (that I saw), that you would not be able to choose a custom node address.

Comment: If that is true, its a bit strange. I see no incentive to limit what node users can connect to with their wallet, unless there is a darker motive.

Comment: imo the incentive is pretty obvious: support. allowing user defined node adds complexity and uncertainty to the support process. if jaxx controls the nodes then they know what they should expect when helping a user with a problem.