# XMR sent from Kraken not visible in wallet

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, monerod, monero-wallet-gui

I'm new to Monero, so please use the most basic explanations. Thanks!

I've sent XMR from Kraken exchange to my Gui wallet a while ago, using an integrated adress. Only I didn't notice that my wallet was not connected at that moment.

Later I connected the wallet using a node from Monero World. Also I've deleted the cache to let the wallet rebuild. I've also checked if the transaction is listed in the blockchain, which is the case. Still, the GUI wallet does on my Macbook not show the right amount of XMR, while it is connected.

What can I do to make my transaction visible in the wallet?

P.S.

I've also downloaded a CLI wallet, but it doesn't recognize the name of my GUI wallet and it doesn't allow me to type any commands.

Comment: Try this solution and note that  the answer was edited to suggest a new node since your question was posted https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/3273/how-can-i-use-monero-without-syncing-the-blockchain

Comment: There was a temporary node issue today. If you experience an issue, you can always try another node https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/2498/is-there-any-remote-node-list-to-connect-simplewallet

Comment: Could you verify, using the "Verifying that your transaction arrived (as a recipient)" part of [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/6v3b2g/psa_you_may_experience_some_transaction_delay_due/) post, that your transaction actually arrived at your address?

Comment: @dEBRUYNE  I would like to, but I don't know how to obtain the viewkey since my cli won't recognize the correct wallet.

Comment: After running a local node on my computer and pushing the Mac Os X to the limit, my XMR are visible in the Gui Wallet. Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: Good to hear you solved your issue :)