# Monerujo deamon adress

Tags: daemon, remote-access, monerujo

I just downloaded the Monerujo wallet and trying to figure it out. Is there an instructions page? I don't know what to put in for a deamon address.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I just downloaded the Monerujo wallet and trying to figure it out. Is there an instructions page?

Yes. Read the [README](https://github.com/m2049r/xmrwallet/blob/master/README.md), [FAQ](https://github.com/m2049r/xmrwallet/blob/master/doc/FAQ.md). As this app is still in APK form and not released to the app store, use caution and read the [disclaimer](https://github.com/m2049r/xmrwallet/blob/master/README.md#disclaimer):

> You may lose all your Moneroj if you use this App. Be cautious when spending on the mainnet.

For maximum privacy, connect to a daemon that you run yourself. You can also choose to use a remote node such as those listed by [MoneroWorld](https://monero.stackexchange.com/a/2976/7):

> node.moneroworld.com at port 18089
>
> node.xmrbackb.one at port 18081
>
> node.xmr.be at port 18081

In order to fit the format required by the Monerujo app use (example from above list): `node.moneroworld.com:18089`