# Wallet RPC error (internal error: "wallet.keys" is opened by another wallet program)

Tags: monero-wallet-rpc, remote-node, public-node

I try to connect to a remote node with `monero-wallet-rpc`.

Every guide that has been shown was how to connect via `monero-wallet-gui` or `monero-wallet-cli`.

I specifically need `monero-wallet-rpc`.

Unfortunately this does not help:
[Is there any remote node list to connect simplewallet?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/2498/is-there-any-remote-node-list-to-connect-simplewallet).

When I connect to a remote node via `monero-wallet-gui` or `monero-wallet-cli`, I cannot connect my wallet anymore because the wallet is already used by the running process:

> E Error locking fd 16: 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable)
> E Failed to lock receivewallet.keys: Resource temporarily unavailable
> E !is_keys_file_locked(). THROW EXCEPTION: error::wallet_internal_error
> E Wallet initialization failed: internal error: "wallet.keys" is opened by another wallet program

How do I connect my wallet to a remote node using `monero-wallet-rpc`?

Answer (score 1):

> `E Wallet initialization failed: internal error: "wallet.keys" is opened by another wallet program`

You can only have your wallet files open by one process at a time. So kill the process you don't want to have it opened by.

> How do I connect my wallet to a remote node using monero-wallet-rpc?

```
monero-wallet-rpc --help
...
    --daemon-address arg          Use daemon instance at <host>:<port>
```