# Using remote node still syncs blockchain?

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, monero-wallet-gui, light-wallet

I have restored my previous wallet with the 25 words key (stored in a different laptop). I don't want to download the whole BC in this new computer, just connect to a remote node. However no matter what option I tried, it seems that all of them lead to a full download?

I followed the instructions here for the command line client: 
[How do I connect monero-wallet-cli to a remote node?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/1401/how-do-i-connect-monero-wallet-cli-to-a-remote-node)

And the instructions here for the GUI client:
https://getmonero.org/resources/user-guides/remote_node_gui.html

In the GUI, starting the daemon will start downloading the BC in ./bitmonero/lmdb something I would like to avoid due to lack of space.

Also in the GUI, if I connect to the remote node, on the lower left part the network status will change to Synchronizing. However it will start from the beginning (1.4M+ blocks). Monitoring the network traffic, it seems that it is downloading the whole BC, even if it is a remote node?

**Is there a quick way to restore my wallet using my 25 words that does not imply downloading the BC (either by using my own node or a remote one)? I am a bit lost on the available options for a "light" client.**

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Monero there's two "syncs". First, the blockchain sync, which is basically downloading the blockchain from other nodes / peers. Second, the wallet sync, which is the wallet "refreshing" / scanning blocks looking for transactions belonging to your address / wallet. Since you're using a remote node, you're skipping the first step. Thus, the status indicator on the left bottom (of the GUI) is showing the number of blocks it still needs to refresh. If it states `Connected` it's fully refreshed and should show your balance.

Now, to make sure you are properly connected to a remote node and restore your wallet, use the following command (**CLI**):

On Windows make sure to launch it from the command line. Go to the folder `monero-wallet-cli` is located and make sure your cursor isn't located on any of the files. Subsequently do SHIFT + right click and it will give you an option to "Open command window here". Lastly, type the following command:

`monero-wallet-cli.exe --daemon-address node.moneroworld.com:18089 --restore-deterministic-wallet`

On Linux and Mac OS X, you need to open a new terminal from the same directory as `monero-wallet-cli` and subsequently type:

`./monero-wallet-cli --daemon-address node.moneroworld.com:18089 --restore-deterministic-wallet`

---

For the **GUI**, go to the wizard (if you currently have a wallet open, go to the `Settings` page and press `Close wallet`, it'll bring you back to the wizard) and (on the second page) set `node.moneroworld.com:18089` as custom daemon address. Subsequently, choose `Restore wallet from keys or mnemonic seed`. As restore height you can use the block height of your first transaction to the wallet minus 10k blocks. Thus, if the first transaction to your wallet was included in block `1410000` you ought to use `1400000` as restore height.

Note that if you want to use a different remote node, simply change `node:moneroworld.com:18089` to the preferred remote node and its port.

Lastly, as user36303 said:

> It does not. It HAS to download something. It just isn't the whole chain.

Answer (score 0):

It does not. It HAS to download something. It just isn't the whole chain.

Comment: How big this something is?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly, but very, VERY roughly, maybe... 5 to 10 GB ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this: from where you had your wallet/BC (your 'different laptop'), export the BC, then transfer that file to your 'new computer' and import the BC.

I'm using a Linux system from the CLI, so I can't advise on any commands that relate the GUIs or MS Windows systems.