# MyMonero is down again, how do I get my money out?

Tags: mnemonic-seed, mymonero, exchange

MyMonero.com is once again down for maintenance.  Is there any way to get my funds out of my wallet, or are they permanently stuck there?

Answer (score 4):

**Yes**, it's possible to get it out, although the process is a bit complicated, because MyMonero does *not* use the standard 25-word seeds.

1. Use https://xmr.llcoins.net to convert your MyMonero 13-word seed into a standard Monero public address, private view key and private send key.

   - This is very risky and requires that you trust the website.  If you don't (and you shouldn't), you'll want to either disconnect the Internet so it can't call home, or [use the source](https://github.com/luigi1111/xmr.llcoins.net) and run it completely offline.
2. Install the [Monero GUI client](https://getmonero.org/downloads/).
3. Initialize an existing wallet using the address & keys you extracted in step 1.
4. [Configure the app to use a remote node](https://getmonero.org/resources/user-guides/remote_node_gui.html), so you don't have to wait days to sync the full blockchain.  (This is safe, but may compromise your privacy to some extent; [details here](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/38/what-privacy-or-security-trade-offs-are-associated-with-not-running-your-own-ful).)
5. Wait until connected and fully synchronized.  If you're having trouble, [try the steps here](https://monero.stackexchange.com/a/6327/2741).
6. Transfer the money out to a new wallet/exchange.
7. Profit!

Comment: Just for the records: When using such websites to convert or generate keys, make sure to do it in a new private (incognito) window and close it afterwards (or / and make sure to disable JavaScript!). When not following this suggestion, websites could in theory still see your key by storing it in eg., your browser's Local Storage. It's best to never use any website at all (be it local / offline).

Comment: @FlorianSchneider The site requires JavaScript, because it does the conversion client-side.  This is much safer than sending the seed to some random server.

Comment: For sure it does the computation happens on client side, otherwise it would be totally flawed. My point is that you need to be _very_ careful when using such a service and ensure it does not store your key inside your browser's Local Store / as a cookie to later send it to a server once you're back online. Therefore: Either open it in a private browser window or even better use a dedicated machine which will never connect to any network.