# Outputs on xmrchain.net show that I have a balance but command line says no balance

Tags: balance

I created a wallet with monero-wallet-gui, then sent my monero from bittrex to the address provided by the monero wallet.  The gui showed a zero balance.  So I checked for the outputs on xmrchain.net:

> Outputs (2)
>
> output public key  amount  output match?
>
> 00: d509fe3dc481125d2962680d69bb89cd27d09dcf81e1f17cdccaa71602f83184
>   ?
>   false
>
> 01: 0b6cfd6dbc3b3d0afc3854eb49857b401f00691c70c8773260580283f4565772   >2.571535700000 
>   true

So I checked the command line:
>

> [wallet 42ozcw]: balance
>   Balance: 0.000000000000, unlocked balance: 0.000000000000

What should I do next?  What am I doing wrong?

I do have an address and a txId.

Answer (score 1):

Chances are your node isn't synced with the blockchain or your wallet isn't refreshed with blockchain data. You can refresh your wallet against either your own node or some open remote node.

There are several options to refresh your wallet. If you want to run a full node note that it requires 32GB storage at the moment but has the advantage that you can later quickly refresh many wallets.

1. Open the GUI and keep it open until it shows "Connected" in the bottom left corner. If it's still catching up, you will see a progress bar and you need to let it finish by keeping it open.

   [image] [image]

   When it says "Connected" then you should see your balance as well. Note that by default, the GUI also runs a node in the background. You can check its status by clicking on the "Settings" tab, and then on "Show status" button.
2. Start `monerod` manually and keep it open until you see "SYNCHRONIZED OK" message. You can check the status by commanding `status` while it's running and you'll see something like:

   ```
   Height: 1424168/1424168 (100.0%) on mainnet, not mining, net hash 242.08 MH/s, v6, up to date, 8(out)+0(in) connections, uptime 0d 18h 46m 58s
   ```

   If it doesn't say 100.0%, means your node has some catching up to do. Then, keep the `monerod` open and start your `monero-wallet-cli` in another window and it should start the refresh automatically. If not, just type `refresh` and it will start. As it finds transactions it will print some lines and at the end show you the final balance.
3. You can skip running a node by telling GUI or CLI to connect to a remote node instead of your own which saves you disk space but wallet refresh is a bit slower compared to a fully synced local node, especially if you have multiple wallets to refresh. You can follow instructions linked below:

   [How do I connect monero-wallet-cli to a remote node?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/1401/how-do-i-connect-monero-wallet-cli-to-a-remote-node)

   https://getmonero.org/resources/user-guides/remote_node_gui.html

Comment: Thanks, JollyMort.

It looks like my app is still synching.  It had given a false "connected" status previously, and seems to do that every now and then.

It now says 'synchronizing'  Blocks remaining:  586123.
It's taking a few days; about 2 so far.

Comment: Are you running the latest version (0.11.0.0) from getmonero.org? On SSD, full sync should take up to 12h IIRC. On spinning disk, a bit longer. Depends on internet connection and CPU as well.

Comment: Yes, I'm running 
GUI version: v0.11.0.0 and 
Embedded Monero version: v0.11.0.0-6-g373ce4a

Comment: Ok, good. If you just want to refresh that one wallet as soon as possible you could try the remote node option. Full node is better IMO, but it requires waiting for the initial sync to complete (later you only need to top-up, or just keep it running all the time) after which any wallet you have will refresh quickly as it will be talking to your own node.