# Help-Sent Monero From Changelly and did not received funds

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, monero-wallet-gui, mymonero, monero-research-lab

I am a total Tech NOOB. I set up the Monero GUI wallet yesterday and moved BTC to Changelly to convert to XMR. Changelly shows the transaction record but something went wrong did not get the funds in wallet. I think it was syncing still. I however have read notes have no real clue how to resolve. If anyone can help in simple step by step I would highly appreciate you!!!! I tried to put the block hash in blockchain tracking sites and said not found. I would appreciate any and all help. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

1. Check that Changly actually sent the funds. Get the TXID from them and try to find it here: https://xmrchain.net/ If they didn't send, you need to work it out with them.
2. If funds were sent, you can verify they were sent to the correct address even if your wallet is not yet up to date: https://monero.stackexchange.com/a/4598/57
3. If you verified it was sent correctly, try this: [Outputs on xmrchain.net show that I have a balance but command line says no balance](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/6345/outputs-on-xmrchain-net-show-that-i-have-a-balance-but-command-line-says-no-bala/6348#6348)