# monero-wallet-cli connection to remote node - Out of Sync

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, wallet, remote-node

I found this site ([*https://www.ditatompel.com/monero/remote-node*](https://www.ditatompel.com/monero/remote-node)) which shows the list of some remote Monero nodes. I would like to connect and be able to use my Monero wallet to send transactions over the testnet network.

When I run

> **monero-wallet-cli --daemon-address**

as suggested in this [*Stack Question*](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/1401/how-do-i-connect-monero-wallet-cli-to-a-remote-node) and i insert my wallet , the result is:

> **[wallet  (out of sync)]:**

The wallet tells me **out_of_sync** and I can neither mine nor execute other commands. Can anyone tell me why? Is the node I'm using the problem? Should I create my own node?

Answer (score 0):

```
[wallet 9xBEEF]: help refresh
Command usage: 
  refresh

Command description: 
  Synchronize the transactions and balance.
```

> Should I create my own node?

Yes.